# Oauth using Jersey server side example?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, oauth, jersey

I'm looking to secure my REST webservice built with Jersey. 
I have seen in the jersey documentation that their is built-in support for oauth 1 on the server and oauth 2 on the client. Oauth 1 would suffice for this project. 
How ever I can't seem to find any good or relevant examples. **That do not use 3th party sides like for instance the twitter web client example.**

Could anyone link me a clear, server side example of jersey REST webservice using oauth.
Using tomcat, jersey, mysql

My regards